# instantiation with variable

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I'm wondering something about Java instantiation. Let's take an example,
I want to instantiate a class depending on some conditions like this:

```
Animal a = null;
if (string.equals("Dog")) a = new Dog();
else if (string.equals("Cat") a = new Cat();
etc...
```

I know it works but I would like to do something like this:
Instead of doing `a = new Dog();`
I want to do something like this: `a = new string();` (with `string` == `"Dog"`)

Basically at runtime, string is replaced by "Dog". I know it is possible with API Reflection (with `Class.forName(string)`).

But is it possible with `new` operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no. The `new` operator creates an object instance based on existing class. Creating a class instance using a string would expose a lot of compilation and runtime problems. If you want to handle this kind of situation you should take a look to the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (and related patterns).

Maybe playing with reflection would give you something for doing this, but I would never consider this approach.